# Is it possible to execute SOLR 4.0 spatial queries from CQL against DSE Search 3.2.0 instance?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, solr4

Is it possible to execute SOLR 4.0 spatial queries from CQL against DSE Search 3.2.0 instance? If yes, what is the correct syntax? In particular my question is about CQL queries referring to a field of a type implemented using solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType class. Running SOLR queries referring to this type against DSE Search 3.2.0 instance  using SOLR Web console works just fine.

Thanks,
Leon

Answer (score 1):

DSE Search CQL only supports basic Lucene syntax, and at this stage it is only provided for development/testing purposes, so you're encouraged to use standard Solr APIs.

Comment: Did anything change in regard to this question in DSE 4.8?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear about usage, normally a "spatial" query is a filter query that is applied to a main query to limit the area of the results while the main query does selection of data by non-spatial attributes such as keywords, but the CQL syntax has only a main query and no provision for any additional Solr query parameters such as filter queries ("fq") or the Solr parameters used by spatial queries.

So, the Solr HTTP API is the only route for spatial queries against DSE data.